# How to detect a string in HTML with Snort?

Tags: snort

I am trying to detect a string in HTML (already unzipped) with Snort. I set this rule to find content `7038685658` in my Apache web server's HTML:

```
alert tcp any any <> any any (msg:"cell"; file_data; content:"7038685658"; sid:9000001)
```

This is the location where the content is:

[image: This is the location where the content is in]

But I can not detect any alert from Snort. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `content` only. Refer to http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node32.html#SECTION004528000000000000000

Comment: I tried, but this wouldn't work as well.

Comment: Your post doesn't reveal anything about your test setup. Silly question but your test site isn't using HTTPS is it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`alert tcp any any <> any any (msg:"cell"; content:"7038685658"; sid:9000001;http_client_body; )`

Make sure you are not loading a cached copy in the browser.

Comment: I tired, but did not work again. I got rid of cash on the browser and renewed the browser several times to detect content. But it did not work too.

Comment: I think you have configuration issue especially LRO. Check this guide (section 8). https://www.snort.org/documents/snort-2-9-9-x-on-ubuntu-14-16